# Change the view to a new view with SplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a very simple design with 3 views (.xib):

- MeuPrimeiroViewController
- MeuSegundoViewController
- MeuTerceiroViewController

I am using the SplitViewController class to divide the screen into two parts, by default is configured on only appdelegate.m class to split views `'MeuPrimeiroViewController'` along with `'MeuSegundoViewController'`.

All Im trying to do is, when the user tap the button inside my `'MeuPrimeiroViewController'`, he start a method existing inside my `'MeuSegundoViewController'` and he push the `'MeuTerceiroViewController'`, for this I'm doing:

**MeuPrimeiroViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)mudar:(id)sender{

    MeuSegundoViewController *VC2 = [[MeuSegundoViewController alloc] init];

    [VC2 mudar];
}
```

**MeuSegundoViewController.m**

```
-(void)mudar{

    NSLog(@"Change Screen");

    MeuTerceiroViewController *VC3 = [[MeuTerceiroViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC3 animated:YES];

}
```

The method 'mudar' is calling but the screen don't change, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the detail view you should make in `MeuPrimeiroViewController`:

```
[self.splitViewController showDetailViewController:VC3 animated:YES];
```

If you want to change the the "list" view you should make in the `MeuPrimeiroViewController`:

```
[self showViewController:VC2 animated:YES];
```

I'm not sure if it's VC2 or VC3 you want to show, but I hope this helps!

Comment: If I want to change the detail controller I use showDetailViewController, who is the code I uso to change the other split?